# Transition matrix in left-right hidden semi-Markov model

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, machine-learning, bayesian-network

I'm developing a hidden semi-Markov model left-right . In a left-right model a sequence of $M$ states starts in state $1$ and ends in state $M$, with no repetition of states. Since the model is semi-Markovian a self transition $a_{ii}=0$ is not allowed. I think the last row of the matrix should be $0$, but the rule is $\sum_{j}a_{ij}=1$. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Why can't you just make the last row whatever you want and just adding stopping criteria to your code? Alternatively, you could make a new $(M+1)$th state where $M \mapsto M+1$ and $M+1 \mapsto M$ and again add to your code logic checking whether you're in state $M$ or $M+1$ (both representing the stopping/halting states).

Comment: There's an absorbing state: $a_{MM} = 1$.

Comment: @PA6OTA I don't think i can because in hidden semi-markov model a self transition is not allowed

Comment: @davin the alternative sounds really good.